# Copying specific text from one file into a schema

Tags: scripting, awk

I have two files.  One being a schema, and the other a list of data.  The schema looks like:

```
line_name:
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
```

and repeats regularly for the number of lines that I have.

The other file is a list of line names and goes:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

I'd like to copy all the line names into just after the line_name field, but I'm really not all that good with awk.  Could anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: This is not very clear. Could you give an example of your desired output? Do you want `line_name: name1 name2 name3` or do you want something more complex? How many lines more or less? Does `cable_edit` not have a `:`? What are the names? Do they contain spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these commands give the following output

```
sed '/line_name/ r linenames' schema
awk '{print} /line_name/ {while (getline < "linenames") print}' schema
```

```
line_name:
name1
name2
name3
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
```

Answer (score 0):

This command *insert* each line of the second file (`linenames`) after each first line in the file `schema`

```
  awk '{print} /line_name/ { getline < "linenames" ; print}' schema
```

with this output

```
line_name:
name1
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
line_name:
name2
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
....
```

This command instead

```
awk '{print} /line_name/ { getline < "linenames" ; print}' schema | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/line_name:\n/line_name: /g'
```

Insert the name just after the tag line_name:

```
line_name: name1
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
line_name: name2
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
line_name: name3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert in the same line with `line_name`:

```
$ awk '/line_name/{getline name < "linenames";$0 = $0" "name}1' schema
line_name: name1
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
line_name: name2
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
line_name: name3
shot_edit:
channel edit:
cable_edit
```

Comment: @ashumeow I believe it would be more clear if you posted your variant of the code separately; then we could decide what the differences between the proposed variants are. I don't believe that editing this suggested code is a good idea, because we might break the intented behavior (intended by he author of the answer).